# Touches on UICollectionViewCell are delayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell with a UILabel. I change the label color when the user touches it. The problem is when you touch the cell the text change or touch isn't recognized until you release your finger.

I think there is a some delay setting that you can set so that the user can scroll the UICollectionView without a selection happening, but I can't find that property?

Comment: By any chance do you have other gesture recognizers within your view controller?

Comment: Nope I do not. There is a property that I can set that will not delay touches.

Comment: Did you look at the `delaysContentTouches` property on `UICollectionView`?

Comment: That is what I am talking about but I just set it and it still isn't work until I release my finger. Guess I will need to put a gesture recognizer on each cell instead of changing the label color in didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Why not add a `UIButton` to the cell that will fire as soon as it's touched to change the label color immediately. `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeLabelColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];`

Answer (score 1):

Standard UIKit behaviour is to trigger activity on touch up inside (i.e. end of touch, finger has to be still inside the control).

In a scroll view such as a collection view, subviews will get the `touchesBegan:` upon finger down but will get a subsequent cancellation if the finger then moves sufficiently to look like a scroll rather than a tap. `UIControl`s and relevant `UIGestureRecognizer`s just process that information. They therefore follow the touch up inside rule and don't fire if the action ends up looking like a scroll.

I doubt there's a way to change collection view behaviour directly but you could have individual cells catch touches began or controls within them post on touch down. Given that `UILabel` is not a subclass of `UIControl` you'd probably need to subclass it and to do the former.